# Objective-C Singletons and LLVM/clang leak warnings

Tags: objective-c, llvm, clang

I'm using the singleton pattern in several places in an application, and I'm getting memory leak errors from `clang` when analyzing the code.

```
static MyClass *_sharedMyClass;
+ (MyClass *)sharedMyClass {
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (_sharedMyClass == nil)
      [[self alloc] init];
  }
  return _sharedMyClass;
}

// clang error: Object allocated on line 5 is no longer referenced after this point and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)
```

I'm using these settings for `scan-build`:

`scan-build -v -v -v -V -k xcodebuild`

I'm fairly certain that the code in the singleton is just fine - after all, it's the same code referenced here on Stack Overflow as well as in Apple's documentation - but I would like to get the memory leak warning sorted out so my scan-build returns success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be being exceptionally dense, but surely your line 5

```
[[self alloc] init];
```

allocates an object of the containing class type, and promptly throws it away? Do you not want

```
_sharedMyClass = [[self alloc] init];
```

?

Comment: Actually the `-init` method sets the static _sharedMyClass variable, so this is fine. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like/145221#145221

Comment: Then I would guess that CLANG isn't smart enough to infer that the [self alloc] return is actually setting the self parameter, which will be saved by the init method. It thus thinks it's just lost (as I did, without more context).

Answer (score 5):

Apple has since updated their [recommended singleton code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) to pass the static analyzer:

```
+ (MyGizmoClass*)sharedManager
{
    if (sharedGizmoManager == nil) {
        sharedGizmoManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedGizmoManager;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[self sharedManager] retain];
}
```

Now `+sharedManager` calls super's `-allocWithZone:` and assigns the return of `-init`, and the singleton's `-allocWithZone:` just returns a retained sharedInstance.

Edit:

Why the retain in +allocWithZone:?

+allocWithZone: is overridden because someone using MyGizmoClass could circumvent the singleton by calling [[MyGizmoClass alloc] init] instead of [MyGizmoClass sharedManager]. It's retained because +alloc is expected to always return an object with a retain count of +1.

Every call to +alloc should be balanced with a -release or -autorelease, so without the retain in +allocWithZone:, the shared instance could potentially be deallocated out from under other users.

Comment: I like this approach but I don't understand the need for the retain in allocWithZone.  Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in a simple, one-method, GCD-based singleton implementation (and thus 10.6+ only) posted on [Mike Ash's site](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html):

```
+ (id)sharedFoo
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Foo *foo = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ foo = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks nice.. Unfortunately I'm actually on the iPhone platform so that's not an option yet.

Comment: GCD is available in iOS 4, so have at it. dispatch_once is definitely the way to go for singletons.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing `self` in a class method!  Big no-no!  Secondly, you are calling `[[self alloc] init]` and just throwing away the instance.  You should assign the singleton reference in the class method, and not in `init` like I am guessing you are doing.  Next, there is no real guarantee that `_sharedMyClass` will be initialized to zero.  You should explicitly initialize it to `nil`.

```
static MyClass *_sharedMyClass = nil;

+ (MyClass *)sharedMyClass {
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (_sharedMyClass == nil)
      _sharedMyClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  }
  return _sharedMyClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also probably had this in there too...

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedInstance;  // assignment and return on first allocation
        }
    }
    return nil; // on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
}
```

The reason you weren't storing it in init is because you were storing it in the method that alloc called.  This is the pattern Apple has in their examples.  If you save the value in your init as well, all is fine and the warning goes away.  I'd leave the allocWithZone implementation alone.